# Calling Service From Broadcastreceiver Issue

Tags: android

I need to use a service inside broadcastreceiver (i start the receiver from an alarmmanager ) but the problem its when i need to call the service. Apparently this never was executed. also i set the debugger to check but also this never attach to the code.

**I dont know why the service never get triggered**

My Receiver Call

```
 private void getHour()
    {
        // use this to start and trigger a service
        Intent i = new Intent( context, getHourService.class );
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService( i );
    }
```

The service

```
public class getHourService extends Service
{
    public int horaR;
    public int minR;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId )
    {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        // Some logical code here  
    }
}
```

I add in the manifest

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Lot of Receivers -->

    <!-- Service -->
    <service android:name="alarmas.getHourService" > </service>

</application>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i called the service from broadcastreceiver but the service never get triggered

Comment: Are you sure the `startService()` call is being executed? Have you added logging to `onStartCommand()` to see if it is being called? Have you checked your logcat for errors?

Comment: Also, remove `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` from `getHour()`. This flag is for starting `Activity`, not for starting `Service`.

Comment: ok after a while, the service was triggered only if call it from onReceive, in a method it doesnt work apparently .- !

Comment: Where is the variable `context` in `getHour()` initialized? With what value?

Comment: in onReceive i do this `this.context = context;`

Comment: if you are calling that method from inside `onReceive()` it should also work. I see no reason why it shouldn't work.